# Includes causing struct alias to not be visible?

Tags: c, struct, include, typedef

In my C project, I have a header file with a declaration of a struct (with an alias) and a header file with functions that accept that struct as an argument (using the alias). I am receiving the error `expected ')' before '*' token` on the function. From researching, I think this indicates that the alias is not visible in the function's namespace. I have a fairly convoluted `include` web that I believe may be causing this. Here is a simplified example.

Struct declaration header:

```
#ifndef STRUCTHEADER_H_
#define STRUCTHEADER_H_
#endif /* STRUCTHEADER_H_ */

#ifndef STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_
#include "structFunctions.h"
#endif


struct myStruct{

};

typedef struct myStruct mys;
```

Struct function header:

```
#ifndef STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_
#define STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_
#endif /* STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_ */

#ifndef STRUCTHEADER_H_
#include "structHeader.h"
#endif

void func(mys* s);
```

main.c:

```
#ifndef STRUCTHEADER_H_
#include "structHeader.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change main.c to this:

```
#ifndef STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_
#include "structFunctions.h"
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

the error goes away. Am I using `include` wrong?

Comment: For me it's the opposite way. It works when `main.c` includes `structFunction.h`, I get an error when it includes `structHeader.h`.

Comment: Thanks, I copied it over wrong. Fixed that now.

Comment: Looks like your header files have header guards, but you've put your code outside them... normally you'd put the meaningful content between eg. `#define STRUCTHEADER_H_` and the following `#endif` so you can safely include the file more than once instead of using `#ifndef ...` around each `#include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `structHeader.h` so that it declares the structure before it includes `structFunctions.h`, because the function definition needs to refer to the alias. In C, you can only refer to names that have been previously declared.

```
#ifndef STRUCTHEADER_H_
#define STRUCTHEADER_H_
#endif /* STRUCTHEADER_H_ */

struct myStruct{

};
typedef struct myStruct mys;

#ifndef STRUCTFUNCTIONS_H_
#include "structFunctions.h"
#endif
```